# Directives not updating in Angular 1.5 component template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the code below, anything in `{{ }}` will update, but directives like `ng-show` and `ng-class` will not...re-run?...when `objects` is updated. They will run once, when the template is compiled, I'm assuming.

```
<div>
  <div
    ng-repeat="object in $ctrl.objects"
    >
    <div>
      {{ $ctrl.showStatus(object.property) }}
    </div>

    <div>
      {{ $ctrl.getClassName(object.property) }}
    </div>

    <div
      ng-show="$ctrl.showStatus(object.property)"
      ng-class="$ctrl.getClassName(object.property)">
      {{ object.name }} - {{ object.property }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


mod.component('pane', {
    bindings: {
        objects: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, service) {
        this.getClassName = function (property) {
            return 'status-'+property.state.name()+'-state';
        };

        this.showStatus = function (property) {
            return property.state !== service.AlarmStates.OK;
        };

    },
    templateUrl: "/templates/panes/alert.html"
});
```